# Onload method is calling itself more than once on successive reloads to application (var image = new Image(), javascript issue)

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I don't understand why onload method(see the code below) is calling itself more than once in IE8 and IE9 browsers on consecutive reloads.

I guess, onload method is fired more than once that is causing this image to `render(appear)` more than once in **IE8,IE9**. Below js code is written by my senior Front-Ender (he is using his own written js library for all `.append()`, `anim()`, ... methods). The code is working as expected in Firefox, Chrome but the `image(html code)` is rendering more than once while reloading with a IE8 or IE9 browser.

Some Quick Info:

- `waitingFor()` - Periodically scans dom for matching elements,
- `mdiTog` - The image that is appearing more than once..

How it works:

The `div` attribute `Class="suggestions contextSuggesions"` is inserted in the `body` element and contains an unordered list (`ul`, `li`, `ul`) that toggles between opacity `0` and `1` if you click on the image (`mdiTog`).

Below is the image of `Mditog` appearing more than once and it's appearance is random:

[image]

```javascript
    waitingFor('.viewport .homePage', function () {
    var mdiTog = new Image();
    mdiTog.onload = function () {
        var $mdi = M$('.mdiTabs ul'),
            $contextMenu = M$($body.append('<div class="suggestions contextSuggesions" style="display:none"></div>')),
            $toggle = M$($mdi.append('<li class="mdiTog" style="display:none"></li>')),
            visible = false,
            active = false;

        var hideCtx = function () {
            if (visible) {
                $contextMenu.anim('', {opacity: 100}, {opacity: 0}, 250, function () {
                    $contextMenu.css({display: 'none'});
                });
                visible = false;
            }
        };              

        $toggle.css({opacity: 0, display: 'inline-block'}).anim('', {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 100}, 1000).on('click', function () {
            var togOS = $toggle.offset(),
                menu = '';

            M$('li', $mdi.get()).each(function (el, idx) {
                if (idx > 1) {
                    menu += '<li rel="' + idx + '">' + $mdi.text(null, el) + '</li>';                   
                }
            });

            $contextMenu.css({opacity: 0, display: 'block', top: togOS.top + 'px', left: (togOS.left - 20) + 'px'}).anim('', {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 100}, 400, function () {
                visible = true;
            }).html('<ul>' + menu + '<li class="uiUtil hr" onclick="ApolloUI.widgets.expose.show()">' + translate('previewAll') + '</li><li class="uiUtil" onclick="ApolloUI.mdi.closeAll()">' + translate('closeAll') + '</li></ul>');
        });

        $contextMenu.on('click', function (e) {
            var target = $contextMenu.eventTarget(e);

            if (target.tagName === 'LI' && target.className.indexOf('uiUtil') === -1) {
                $contextMenu.fire('click', M$('.mdiTabs li').get(parseInt(target.getAttribute('rel'), 10)));
            }
            hideCtx();              
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
            active = false;
        }).on('mouseenter', function () {
            active = true;
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            if (!active && visible) {
                hideCtx();
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
    mdiTog.src = 'media/img/ico_16_context.png';
});
```

I do have to close this issue as soon as possible, so any suggestions/modifications/addition in this code to force onload to execute only once on even on several consecutive reloads in IE8/IE9 browsers are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Wouter J, i will keep in mind these things next time i ask a question, but there is no method as render(call) - it was supposed to be appearing/rendering on the web page, so made the change as it would confuse the reader.

Comment: So the `onload` fires twice sometimes? Please narrow down the issue. Also, are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, you can say that, as i inspected using developer tools the image and the HTML code `<li class="mdiTog"></li>` (that image - mdiTog) is appearing more than once. Further, i am not using jquery, this code is written by my senior dev. and he used his hand-crafted MkiScript - javascript library. Thanks for the suggestion, i guess the onload function is firing more than once.

Comment: [That one](http://mkiscript.com/)? However, all these `M$` things seem to work *like* jQuery.

Comment: yup, it's equivalent to `$` in jquery, even most of the functions work like jquery, but Mkiscript is 3kb minified and quite fast.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the onload fires twice, you should use a guard against executing the handler more than once:

```
var mdiTog = new Image();
var hasFired = false;
mdiTog.onload = function () {
   if (hasFired)
       return;
   hasFired = true;

   …
};
```

Or, if you're using a jQuery-like library, you could try the `one` event binding method:

```
var mdiTog = new Image();
M$(mdiTog).one("load", function () {
    …
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi for the answer, first i will implement it on monday and then only will accept the answer.. :)